# Drupal, broken view, need help

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am getting strange problem.

When I am listing some content type, intead of data I am getting 'n/a' string.
I listed views, and on one view I have 'Warning - Broken view!' message.
I can't edit / delete this view because it always redirect to front page.

I checked my logs and all I see is repeating:

```
# warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/www/testetelgsm/www/includes/common.inc on line 3364.
# warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/www/testetelgsm/www/modules/cck/content.module on line 1284.
# warning: array_keys() [function.array-keys]: The first argument should be an array in /home/www/testetelgsm/www/includes/common.inc on line 3361.
```

How can I delete / edit this view?
Could somebody help?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the views admin page at: admin/build/views. Here you can find a list of all your views and edit/delete them.

It sounds like you are trying to pull something that doesn't exist anymore like a deleted cck field. Anyways, if it doesn't work to edit it, try to recreate it.

You can make views into features with the features module. That will define the views in a custom module that is generated for you, and make the view defined in code. That will make it possible to restore it, if it gets edited.